# columns with ng-repeat in ionic are not separating into rows

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat

The main problems I am experiencing are solely related to my code's inability to display the badges in multiple rows of 3 columns without repeating the same badges in each row. Even though I identify col-33, the badges are appearing in the row (evenly spaced in 33%) for more than full width of the page; they overflow off the page! I have tried setting max-width to no avail. Please, any advice would be great, here is the code:

```
  <ion-content class="badge-bg">
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="row in badgesCtrl">
      <div class="col-33" ng-show="badge.images[0].url" ng-repeat="badge in badgesCtrl.badges ">
        <img ng-click="badgesCtrl.viewBadgeDetail(badge)"
             alt="" src="{{badge.images[0].url}}" alt="color" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
```

Controller

```
 .controller('BadgesCtrl', ['$location', '$routeParams', '$scope', '$state', '$ionicPopover', 'BadgesService',
function($location, $routeParams, $scope, $state, $ionicPopover, BadgesService) {
  $ionicPopover.fromTemplateUrl('templates/popover.html', {
    scope: $scope,
  }).then(function(popover) {
    $scope.popover = popover;
  });

  badgesCtrl = this;
  $scope.search = {};
  $scope.search.searchText = '';

  // Initialize badges Data
  BadgesService.getBadges().success(function(badges) {
    badgesCtrl.badges = badges;
  });

  BadgesService.getBadge($routeParams.badgeId).success(function(badge){
    badgesCtrl.badge = badge;
  });

  badgesCtrl.viewBadgeDetail = function(badge) {
    $location.path('/tab/badges/' + badge._id);
  };
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `badgesCtrl` is your controller where you've put functions like `viewBadgeDetail` on there to use, but then you use `badgesCtrl` in the first `ng-repeat` like it's a collection. Did you mean `ng-repeat="row in badgesCtrl.rows"`? Seems like you should then also be referencing `row.badges` in the second `ng-repeat` instead of `badgesCtrl.badges`.

This way you're iterating over a collection of `rows` and then each `row` has it's own collection of badges unique to that `row`.

First `ng-repeat`:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="row in badgesCtrl.rows">
```

Second `ng-repeat`:

```
<div class="col-33" ng-show="badge.images[0].url" ng-repeat="badge in row.badges">
```

---

If you have a collection of badges, say at `badgesCtrl.badges` and you want it divided up so it works like what I have above, then try this out:

```
badgesCtrl.rows = [];
var count = 0;
var currentRow = { badges: [] };
badgesCtrl.badges.forEach(function (badge, index) {
  currentRow.badges.push(badge);
  count++;
  // If count is 3 or we are at the end of the badges collection
  // then push our current row and start counting again.
  if (count === 3 || index === badgesCtrl.badges.length - 1) {
    badgesCtrl.rows.push(currentRow);
    count = 0;
    currentRow = { badges: [] };
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your help. I am sort of jumping in on this code mid way through and am having some trouble making sense of the controller. I have added the controller in my edit.

Comment: Thank you again for your help! I have tried the above code and am receiving this error in the console: TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined